# Fast search of proper XML file in folder

Tags: java

If I have 100 short XML files in folder and I'd like to know which of them contains text `aaabbbccc` (for later accurate parsing). Is this a good idea to read them as `String`s one after other and try to use `contains`  function to determine what files not contains this text?

As I know the `contains` function is *very* fast.

Comment: Depends specifically on the info you have on hand. contains implies that the string you are looking for could be anywhere in each file, however, if you know for a fact that it is at the beginning (just an example), then I would limit your code to specify that. Basically, any outside info you have, use that to get rid of unnecessary work

Comment: no, a text could be anywhere and not only once.. I am thinking about implementing two -step filtering. On the first step get rid of crap files and on the second parse the needed ones BUT every good file will be loaded twice in such case(( this is not good

Comment: You need to be careful if the searched string can possibly exist as ampersand XML entities. If you don't control the generation of the file, in some circumstances, this might open you up to security vulnerabilities (e.g. if the file you rejected here is processed by a code that makes the assumption that it does not contain the string but turns out it does). You can do this in one pass, most XML Parsing library can accept reading from String just as well as reading from file. Other than that, I don't see any issues if this is only as optimization.

Comment: 100 small files sounds like it's not worth searching first. You have to implement the parsing anyway, so I'd do that first. When the file is parsed, checking for the text should be easy. Do this and only bother implementing a file search if that turns out to be too slow. (Or just use `grep` for the filtering.)